# Can not open ".jar" file in windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, java, jre, jar

I downloaded a jar application named [Need for speed most wanted](http://www.java-mobiles.net/tag/games/need-for-speed-most-wanted-get-253607.html). I double clicked on the jar file icon, however it did not execute.

I checked I have jre installed in my windows 8 (64 bit) machine in path "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin" and there is also javaw file.

I saw some link like [Running Jar file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows), [how to run .jar file by double click on windows 7 (64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64) and [Can't Run JAR Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724892/cant-run-jar-files) but none of them helped me.

I also installed [Jarfix](http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html) and used it. Any way it does not work for me.

I tried to run jar application using command prompt using command:

```
java -jar "NeedForSpeedMostWanted"
```

But I get error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile NeedForSpeedMostWanted
```

And I tried adding .jar extension to command:

```
java -jar "NeedForSpeedMostWanted.jar"
```

But again I get another error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in NeedForSpeedMostWanted.jar
```

So what else I must check to run my jar file.

Comment: Are you trying to run *Java Mobile Game* on PC ?? I believe you cannot run them directly without a mobile emulator.

Comment: Where can I find a simple jar application for testing whether my windows can open jar application or not?

Comment: Here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/CatalogJar.htm

Comment: Thanks, now I download jar file in http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcontentmanager18jar.htm but it does not work. I dabble clicked and it does not open.

Comment: I think those *jar* files are not standalone binaries.
Ok, try this http://sourceforge.net/projects/tictactoe-javab/

Comment: Yes It works! Can you add your comment as answer so I can checked it as answer? And can you help me why a jar file in http://sourceforge.net/projects/erframework/files/ does not open?

Comment: The JAR file http://sourceforge.net/projects/erframework/files/BlockingFramework.jar does not contain any Main-Class that's why giving an error. Type `java -jar BlockingFramework.jar` on `cmd` to see the error. I don't have much knowledge about JAVA, and I think you should refer to their documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your Original Question, the *JAR* file you are downloading is meant for *Java Micro Edition* running on Mobile Devices. So you cannot directly run those *JAR'S* on PC unless you have a mobile emulator ([here](http://geek.ng/2012/02/best-3-emulators-to-run-mobile-java-jar-games-apps-on-your-windows-pc.html))

As you have stated in your comment you only want to test if a *JAR* file is runnable or not, you can find various online. One of them [Tic-Tac-Toe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tictactoe-javab/). Or you can pack your own *JAR* and test them.

Answer (score 1):

The game you downloaded is for a mobile phone device i.e java micro edition available only on mobile phones

To run the game on a PC you should dowload a Java mobile emulator for the PC

Download emulator from here [Java Mobile Emulators](http://geek.ng/2012/02/best-3-emulators-to-run-mobile-java-jar-games-apps-on-your-windows-pc.html)

Comment: Where can I find a simple jar application for testing whether my windows can open jar application or not?

Answer (score -1):

Probably it's because you are using jre8. The jar file you downloaded may not be compatible with it. Try a lower version: jre6 or jre7.